# Testing a simple function call with clojure.test

Tags: clojure, clojure-testing

I'm just starting to play with Clojure and am having difficulty with something basic. I want to just test a simple function that does 1 + 1.

Here's `core.clj`

```
(ns core)

(defn run []
  (+ 1 1))
```

Here's the test, `core-test.clj`

```
(ns core-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [core :refer :all]))

(deftest a-test
  (testing "Core"
    (is (= 2 run))))
```

Here's the result

```
lein test core-test

lein test :only core-test/a-test

FAIL in (a-test) (core_test.clj:7)
Core
expected: (= 2 run)
  actual: (not (= 2 #object[core$run 0x12f8b1d8 "core$run@12f8b1d8"]))

Ran 1 tests containing 1 assertions.
1 failures, 0 errors.
Tests failed.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not calling `run`.  Right now you are comparing `2` with the function.  Use `(= 2 (run))`.